# How can i resolve warning message 'BUG IN CLIENT OF libsqlite3.dylib: database integrity compromised by API violation' in Sqlite.swift?

Tags: ios, swift, integrity, sqlite.swift

i'm using Sqlite.swift

when i restart app in simulator, i want to remove existing database and make new database. (because of initializing database... i change the database column a lot.)

but there is warning message.

```
[logging] BUG IN CLIENT OF libsqlite3.dylib: database integrity compromised by API violation: vnode unlinked while in use:
```

i know it's about integrity...  but i don't know how can i resolve the problem.

here is my code. when you click the button 'Create', func createDB() will work.

```swift
    func createDB() {
        print("CREATE DB")
        do {

            let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)

            let fileUrl = documentDirectory.appendingPathExtension("test").appendingPathExtension("sqlite3")

            // if there is existing db, then remove it
            let fileMng = FileManager.default
            if fileMng.fileExists(atPath: fileUrl.path) {
                do {
                    try fileMng.removeItem(at: fileUrl)
                    print("remove db file because you already have db")
                }
                catch {
                    print("Remove DB Error", error)
                }
            }

            let database = try Connection(fileUrl.path)
            self.database = database
            print("Successfully create database")
        }
        catch {
            print("Create DB Error : ", error)
        }
    }
```

and this is log.

```
CREATE DB
remove db file because you already have db
Successfully create database
CREATE DB
remove db file because you already have db
2020-04-13 23:01:36.866156+0900 RealmTest[40604:6719249] [logging] BUG IN CLIENT OF libsqlite3.dylib: database integrity compromised by API violation: vnode unlinked while in use: {directory-address-in-my-local-computer}
2020-04-13 23:01:36.866272+0900 RealmTest[40604:6719249] [logging] invalidated open fd: 5 (0x11)
Successfully create database
```

i found out this is not error, but warning. and when i restart app, the removing operation work very well without warning message. but when i second click the button 'Create', the warning message alerts.

i didn't delete the database when I turned off the app. therefore, i think it is clear that the database will be deleted when the app is turned on again. so i don't know what the problem is with creating a db twice. I'd really appreciate it if you could tell me! Please let me know.

Comment: I've been getting this problem while creating a temporary persistent storage using SwiftData in unit tests.  After each test when it tears down the container it spits out this warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure that before you call your `createDB()` method, any pending connections to your database are closed. You have at least one such connection in your code, in `self.database` so you need to set that to nil.

```
self.database = nil
self.createDB()
```

(Alternatively, you can to that inside `createDB()`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a better solution, but for what it's worth -- I am getting the same error when I try to delete and recreate my database in a Google Drive folder on my Mac, but not when I use a local folder such as my home directory.